# how to sort array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have data like this in mysql sort by id ASC:

**NOTE: total is not in mysql, total is from price * total_item -> for example**

```
     id       name         total
    ----   -----------   ----------
     1        item1          3
     2        item2          5
     3        item3          1
     4        item4          2
     5        item5          4
```

and I want to sort it in php

first, I sort the total to get the highest total in first place

```
//insert total into list
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
  $total_list[] = $total;
  $b = $total_list;
  rsort($b);

  //display total from highest to lowest
  echo $b[$i];
}
```

the result will be like this:

```
         id       name         total
        ----   -----------   ----------
         1        item1          5
         2        item2          4
         3        item3          3
         4        item4          2
         5        item5          1
```

ok, I already got the total sorted according to my code above

so to get the name sorted too, I have to sort it but I already tried the same way as I sorted the total but the result is different

nah, I want the result is like this

```
         id       name         total
        ----   -----------   ----------
         1        item2          5
         2        item5          4
         3        item1          3
         4        item4          2
         5        item3          1
```

Comment: Why don't you do the sort in your mysql select? Like: select * from table name order by total, name

Comment: @deceze - no I think, it's not duplicate

Comment: @bitfiddler - no, because total is not in mysql

Comment: Where does the total column come from?

Comment: @danny beckett - it's from price * total_item -> for example

Comment: If you're calculating total in your query, you can sort by it.  Why don't you post your query?

Answer (score 1):

This can (and should) all be done from the SQL query; something like:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `price` * `total_item` AS `total`
FROM `mytable`
ORDER BY
  `price` * `total_item` DESC,
  `id` ASC
```

When `ORDER`ing, you can't use the name given in `AS`, but you *can* order on the same calculation.

Comment: but the total_item is not in mysql

Comment: Where is it from? I saw you said it was in `COUNT(\`id\`)`, but then you deleted that comment. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah count(id), but total_item is not in mysql, it's from sum of $total_demand and number of demand is in table demand. and I have 3044 record in table item and 60.000 record in table demand, so if i use join table, it's impossible, so i prefer array in php not in mysql

Comment: If you edit your question to contain your full query, I can give you the exact query you could use.

Comment: can you help in array php not query? because I am already half way to finish it and from the start i dont use function sum, average in mysql, I purely use logic math like $a += $a in php to get the sum of $a

Comment: The thing is, you're putting your server under much more stress by doing this in PHP. By doing it in SQL, you get unparalleled performance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this: using `asort`

```
$data = array(
"item1"=>"1",
"item2"=>"2",
"item3"=>"5",
"item4"=>"3",
"item5"=>"4"
);

asort($data);

print_r($data);

Resut: Array ( [item1] => 1 [item2] => 2 [item4] => 3 [item5] => 4 [item3] => 5 )
```

In order to obtain the `highest total value and name`, get the last element on the array. Though you can manipulate the names and keys by using `foreach`.

If we add foreach like this:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
    echo "Name:".$key."  Total:".$val."<br>";
}

Result:

Name:item1 Total:1
Name:item2 Total:2
Name:item4 Total:3
Name:item5 Total:4
Name:item3 Total:5
```

Comment: so how to make the name and the total in the same array like this:

$data = array(
"item1"=>"1",
"item2"=>"2",
"item3"=>"5",
"item4"=>"3",
"item5"=>"4"
);

Comment: no, that's not I want to ask, I want to ask how to get the name and the total together in array?

Comment: @Rio Eduardo Sorry I just updated my answer, you can create an array like that: example, `$data[$name]=$total`. You may study first on php arrays.

Comment: I forgot that I have another atribute except name that is number serial, so how can i sort the number serial too?

Comment: how can i sort the number serial too together with name and total? Thanks

Comment: @Rio Eduardo I can think only of creating another array for serial number. In this case, you need the `names` as key of your array of serial number similar to an array for `total`. So, you will have the `names` as keys for both serial number and total. Then you can manipulate your arrays to your desired output.